# Cancelling a task in a callback from a 3rd party library

Tags: .net, task

In my code I am creating a task that calls a 3rd party library. This library can take a long time. It has a callback to provide status on where it's at (used to update my UI to let the user know this work is progressing).

I don't have access to the code in this library - it is what it is. Can I throw an exception in the callback to force that to get propagated back to where I called the library. Yes it works, but is there any downside to doing this inside a task?

And any downside to my throwing an OperationCanceledException? Or should only the task code throw that?

Comment: Only the people who have access to the code of that library, i.e. its authors, can answer this question. Anything else is just speculation on our part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If indeed the third-party code will stop when an exception is thrown in its status callback, you sure could use that.  You'll need to fully understand how this third-party code handles such a case.  Maybe it stops gracefully and cleans up resources using try/finally before bubbling up the exception.  Maybe it doesn't.

If you started that in a `Task`, and the third-party code doesn't catch that exception internally, then by default the exception would flow to the `Task.Exception` and the status would become `TaskStatus.Faulted`.

What kind of exception you throw isn't really important, as long as it isn't caught except where you want it to be caught.  Throwing an `OperationCanceledException` would work, but recognize that it doesn't automatically set other `CancellationToken` instances else to be cancelled.  You'd have to do that separately on the associated `CancellationTokenSource`.